# Array for python 3.8: F403 F405

Tags: python, arrays

I'm currently learning python arrays and trying to follow along however my import array is giving me some issues and not to sure why. I've done a bit of research and the solutions aren't working either.

The code I'm being asked to use is

from array import *(Which doesn't work)

Then I tried

from numpy import array (This gives no errors but doesn't load the array sample)

from array import array

import array as arr

nothing working so far and the error it is giving me is

F403 -- from array import * used; unable to detect undefined names

F405 -- arry may be undefined, or defined from star imports: array

Array Sample

```
arr = array("i", [])
x = int(input("Enter size of the array"))
print("Enter %d elements" % x)
for i in range(x):
    n = int(input())
    arr.append(n)
    print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the import, it's important to not have overlapping names for symbols. It's like having two people called "John" in a room and calling their name - who is being addressed?

Try this:

```
import array as arr

a = arr.array('i') # i is for unsigned int
```

now you can call

```
a.append(5)
```

on this instance of the array object

Here's some background on aliasing of imports in Python:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-modules-in-python-3#aliasing-modules

More background on arrays here:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/array.html

Are you sure that you need arrays for what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe a list is sufficient for your usecase:

https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/

Answer (score 0):

> F403 -- from array import * used; unable to detect undefined names
>
> F405 -- arry may be undefined, or defined from star imports: array

These are *warnings* from an automatic style-checker, or *linter*, such as pyflakes or pylint.  They are telling you that while the line `from array import *` is valid python, it makes it more difficult to analyse the rest of the code because the style-checker doesn't know which names are imported from `array` and which names have been introduced in error by the programmer.

If you are following a course you can ignore these warnings for now, or satisfy the style-checker by replacing

```
from array import *
```

with

```
from array import array
```

Comment: The tutorial I'm trying to follow along is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlP5kF1_efE&list=PLEiEAq2VkUUKoW1o-A-VEmkoGKSC26i_I&index=19

Answer (score -1):

The python version of arrays are called lists (I think due to the internal implementation). But they are very simple to use:

Python lists don't have types, and can be declared as below:

```
# arr = array("i", [])
arr = []
```

Python lists dynamically resize, so no need to check what size it should be

```
# x = int(input("Enter size of the array"))
```

Just rewording the quote so it makes sense

```
# print("Enter %d elements" % x)
print("Enter your elements")
```

do-while loop to get the user's numbers

```
n =input()
while n:    # Python will evaluate an empty string as False, and all other values as true
    # Convert our number into an int, and append it to the list
    arr.append(int(n))
    print(arr)

    # ask for the next number
    n = input()
```

## Further reading:

[Python Docs on Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: The OP isn't using lists, they are using arrays from the standard library's array module.

Comment: The tutorial I'm trying to follow is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlP5kF1_efE&list=PLEiEAq2VkUUKoW1o-A-VEmkoGKSC26i_I&index=19